# Request based intrusion detection in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, intrusion-detection

I'm wondering if there is a way to push tomcat requests through a custom class easily (e.g without having to heavily modify the codebase) to do things like running a regex to check for XSS and SQL Injection attacks and deny them/sanitize them based on this knowledge.

Thanks

Comment: The general advice is not to go that road as it's impossible to create patterns covering all sorts of XSS/SQL injections, let alone dealing with false positives.

Comment: @mindas then how would you do it?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way of solving XSS/SQL injections. Your suggestion is better than nothing, but the only proper way of fixing problems is to follow common practices (always using prepared statements, using web frameworks that do validation/sanitation and are immune to XSS, etc.). OTOH you need to do some estimation and see what are the business costs of a potential break-in and how much do you want to invest. Who knows, maybe a filter will end up as the preferred choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course - use a Filter:

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+xss+filter
http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+servlet+filter

Comment: This is spot on, thanks a lot, sorry for asking such a simple question, not been working with Tomcat for long.

Comment: No worries, it's a fine question.